# How to get the simple name of the ZipEntry?

Tags: java, android

I would know if is it possible to get the simple name from a `ZipEntry`...

When I invoke the `getName()` of the Entry, I get a full path name.

I need get only the file's name.

Here I need get the simple name instead the full name with its root.

```
public class ZipFileSample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            ZipFile zip = new ZipFile(new File("C:\\Users\\Levi\\Desktop\\jessica.zip"));

            for (Enumeration e = zip.entries(); e.hasMoreElements(); ) {
                ZipEntry entry = (ZipEntry) e.nextElement();
                //Here I need to get the simple name instead the full name with its root
                System.out.println(entry.getName());
            }

        } catch (ZipException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

How about

```
new File(entry.getName()).getName()
```

Comment: Thanks njzk2, this works ok, the only problem is that i need create a new File() to achieve the desired result, but lets forward.

Comment: you don't actually create a file, you create an object that represent a file. there is not necessarly an underlying actual file

Comment: exactly, that's what I meant. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

you can try with below code ( may be you would need to take some precaution for java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException). Also you can enforce some check if you know the extension

```
        try {
            ZipFile zip = new ZipFile(new File("F:\\OTHERS\\classes.zip"));
            for (Enumeration e = zip.entries(); e.hasMoreElements(); ) {
                ZipEntry entry = (ZipEntry) e.nextElement();
                //Here I need to get the simple name instead the full name with its root
                String name =entry.getName();
                //if( name.endsWith(".java"))
//              {
                    name = name.substring(name.lastIndexOf("/")+1,name.length() );
                    System.out.println(name );
//              }
            }

        } catch (ZipException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
```

Comment: to add-up, above logic will only print file names, and not folder names.

Comment: are you actually sure the directory separator is a / ? and is it possible that a file name contains a / ?

Comment: Instead of '/' we can use File.separator. File name never contains '/', so you would get complete file name. lastIndex("/") returns -1 if the name does not contains any separator, so the effective operation is substring(0,length)

Comment: what makes you so sure a filename doesn't contain '/' ?

Comment: What  software (OS) creates file contains '/' .

Comment: see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filename#Comparison_of_filename_limitations for a list of reserved charaters by FS. You can see that not all FS forbid the use of a '/' (although most do)

Comment: Anyway windows doesn't allow you to create files contains '/\:*?<>|' . I am curious to know how can we do that

Comment: how is windows relevant here ? Also, i don't know of any actual limitation to file names in a zip file (i could find anything to this regard)

Comment: My comment was just before you post wiki link,  that is quite useful .  But any I can improve the code by using File.separator instead of '/'. That should make the program  works any where.

Answer (score 0):

String name = name.substring(name.lastIndexOf("/")+1);